# Call data from database into table with rowspan

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have table "Owner" in my database where one of the field (System) saved data from a textarea box.

Table Owner;

```
staf_id || name || system
```

Below is an example of input of the textarea box;

```
aimsweb
elearning
registration
```

The example shows that each line represent different types system. How am I going to call data from the system field to the table below?

[table http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/1170/31920845.png](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/1170/31920845.png)

When it is called, the columns "Staf ID" and "Name" will increase its rowspan based on the input in the textarea. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : I know how to call it into the table but when a textarea is saved into the database, it will display the data display horizontally. Not exactly like the input where there is a new line at each value. Another thing is that, I want it to be displayed it with a rowspan based on the number of each line.

Comment: Ok, I removed my previous comment as I've misread your question. Tbh I've read it over 10 times without understanding so far, now after reading @jeshurun's answer it makes some sense though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you could use:

```
$rows_in_text_area = explode( "\n", $system );
```

Which should give you the number of rows of text in the text area. From there it should be straight forward to use the `$rows_in_text_area` for the rowspan in the staff ID and name cells like this:

```
<td rowspan="$rows_in_text_area">$name</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

"The example shows that each line represent different types system." - this is an example of bad table structure. You should have a new table System with the following columns (example: StaffID, System

But if you want to use it this way and going back to your question:no it will not increase the rowspan. It will just make the System cell bigger. If you did not convert new line characters into 
 not even that because text will display in a single row.